# hibernate validator not found in classpath

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I write custom annotation

```
package ru.tinkoff.bpm.verificationcheckservice.support.validation

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CompositionType
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ConstraintComposition
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL
import javax.validation.Constraint
import javax.validation.Payload
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.FIELD
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@ConstraintComposition(CompositionType.AND)
@URL
@NotBlank
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Target(FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [])
annotation class NotBlankUrl(
    val message: String = "must be not blank and valid URL",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

I add dependency for build.gradle.kts

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:7.0.1.Final")
```

Gradle resolve it in report
https://scans.gradle.com/s/ddjce3iwnldt4/dependencies?dependencies=valida&expandAll&focusedDependency=WzEsOCwxNDk2LFswLDEsWzE5XV1d

But when i start application i see error

```
The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath
```

full logs https://scans.gradle.com/s/ddjce3iwnldt4/console-log#L101

Why spring does not recognize validator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate Validator 6 and below implements the Java EE Bean Validation API.

Hibernate Validator 7 implements the (newer) Jakarta Bean Validation API, which is almost the same but with the `javax.validation` package renamed to `jakarta.validation`.

As far as I know, Spring Framework is still using Java EE Bean Validation.

So what you are doing will not work. The message is correct, there is no implementation of **Java EE** Bean Validation in your classpath; only an implementation of **Jakarta** Bean Validation, and Spring Framework doesn't support that.

For now, if you want to use Spring Framework, you're stuck with Hibernate Validator 6.