# Hibernate validation can't find provider

Tags: java, json, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to use the Hibernate validator, with Java 11 (no Spring or Springboot), but it can't seem to find the proper combination of dependencies.  I have the following dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>
            <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
```

I can't seem to find the right combination that works

The code I'm using is

```
Validator VALIDATOR = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = VALIDATOR.validate(object);
```

## Update

Here's evertyhing I've tried.  I've pretty much thrown the kitchen sink in there and just keep getting the same error

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.0.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hibernate validator not found in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69075274/hibernate-validator-not-found-in-classpath)

Comment: I'm not using Spring or Springboot

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate Validator 8 is based on Jakarta. this means that if you want to use it you should add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
dependency>
```

if you want to use the javax classes then you need to go with latest 6.2 version of hibernate validator

see here for 8.0 documentation - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-createproject

Comment: Just wanted to add that using HV 6.2 is a perfectly viable option as it's maintained and has the same feature as HV 7.0 and 8.0. You need some sort of consistency in the javax/jakarta artifacts you are using so pick a version that is consistent with the framework you are using.

Comment: I'm afraid that switching to jakarta.validation-api still doesn't work.  I also tried downgrading to Hibernate 6.2.5.Final.  I will update the question with everything I have tried

Comment: hmm in such a case I'd suggest to try and run mvn dependency:tree and see if the validator or validation-api are not transiently brought by something else. And also double check the imports to make sure that everything is matching. If that doesn't help - maybe you could create a small reproducible project?

Answer (score 0):

hibernate-validator has been moved to group org.hibernate.validator

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I realized that.  I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After wasting almost a day the below combination worked some how. Pasting here if it helps any one.

`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
<version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>6.2.5.Final</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
<version>3.0.4</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

`